# Size of dropdown / selection list in Libre Office Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

With the data validation tool I made a list of categories that are shown in a selection list for easier data entry. This list is very small and I cannot just enlarge it with the mouse (see screenshot).

[image]

Is there a way to enlarge this list so that I can see all entries at once?

Comment: I haven't figured out a way to control the format of a list created via Data Validity.  But you can create your own and control its features.  From the menu: `View | Toolbars | Form Controls`.  That has an icon to toggle design mode.  A list box or combo box are among the options you can insert and customize.  Documentation starts here: https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Form_Controls.  I've never used it so can't be much help beyond that.